# Outputing to generic port using outb in AT&T assembly syntax: getting operand mistatch

Tags: assembly

I am trying to "outb" to a port but I keep getting: operand type mismatch for `out'

Here is the code:

```
outb  %al, %bl
```

If I replace %bl with any 8 bit register (%ah, %bh, %bl, ...) I still get same error.

If I hard code the port number, then the code works.

How can I write generic way (in assembly) to write to a port passed as parameter?

The following code seems to work in C but I do not really understand why and how:

```
asm volatile ( "outb %0, %w1" : : "a"(val), "Nd"(port) );
```

Thank you

Comment: We actually prefer that things like "Thank you" not appear anywhere in posts as they don't add any useful information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`outb` has a limited number of instruction encodings. The only six encodings are:

```
outb imm8, %al
outb imm8, %ax
outb imm8, %eax

outb %dx, %al
outb %dx, %ax
outb %dx, %eax
```

**No other registers can be used for this instruction.** The port must be in `%dx` or specified as an immediate value, and the value must be in `%eax`, or one of its smaller relatives. (In this sense it's somewhat similar to `mul`, `idiv`, and the shift instructions, in that some of the operands can only be in one specific register.)

Reference: http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_222.html

Comment: Just to clarify, while `The only three encodings which output to a port addressed by a register`, if you want to hard code your port number (which the OP does when he uses "Nd"), then there are 3 more alternatives (still using variations of eax).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Correct. The question specifically recognized that a constant port was different, though. ("If I hard code the port number, then the code works.")

Comment: @duskwuff I think the issue is that anyone who comes to read this answer will see this in bold **There are no other valid combinations.**. There are other combinations if the port number fits in an _imm8_ (port is constant < 256). I know what you meant since you did say _The only three encodings which output to a port addressed by a  REGISTER are:_. I'd reword the valid combinations by clarifying that is when the port number is in a register

Comment: Michael and I were being a bit nit-picky, but your update makes the answer much better.

Comment: Thank you. %dx worked. I thought the port had to be a byte. Thank you all

Comment: @Makketronix Ports are actually 16 bits! The first serial port uses ports 0x3f8 through 0x3ff, for instance.